# Wordpress custom fields - nesting foreach

Tags: wordpress, foreach

I'm a wordpress beginner.

I have some custom fields that contain multiple values, and I want to output them. 
One custom field has multiple values (press review quotes for a show - reviewchart-review). But I also want it to output the corresponding value in the reviewchart-publication field (the name of the publication the press quote is from).

This is the code:

```
$post_meta_array = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'reviewchart-review');
$review_pub = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'reviewchart-publication');

foreach ($post_meta_array as $post_meta) {  
  echo $review_pub . '<blockquote><p>' . $post_meta . '</p></blockquote>';
}
```

This is the output:

```
Array
"Fresh and assured. This Restoration comedy has japes aplenty. Winning performances from Susannah Fielding and Geoffrey Streatfeild."

Array
“Simon Godwin’s production of George Farquhar’s play is one of the most consistently funny productions of a Restoration comedy you’re likely to see.”
```

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: What is  reviewchart-review and reviewchart-publication meta value in db .?

Comment: reviewchart-review meta value is "Fresh and assured.... etc" and "Simon Godwin's.... etc"

Comment: reviewchart-publication is coming out as "Array" at the moment but should be The Guardian and The Times. Thanks

Comment: Just checking if anyone could help me with this :)